# dynamixel_motor debs in Fuerte

Tags: ros, ros-fuerte, dynamixel-motor

[image: Rosanswers logo]

As far as I can tell, the dynamixel_motor stack is not being released as debs for fuerte. Is fuerte not going to release these stacks as debs anymore, and we should be checking them out ourselves, or is it just not packaged yet?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/33985/dynamixel_motor-debs-in-fuerte/) by [John Hoare](https://answers.ros.org/users/159/john-hoare/) on ROS Answers with karma: 765 on 2012-05-14

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

John, I haven't had a chance to test out dynamixel_motor stack with Fuerte yet, hence there are no debs yet. I should have some more time later this week, I will try and push a Fuerte release then. If anybody wants to do a source checkout and try it with Fuerte, that would be great. I don't really anticipate any major problems, since it has pretty minimal ROS dependencies.

**Update:** the trunk of dynamixel_motor stack is now Fuerte compatible, I also did a release into Fuerte, but it will take some time before it's built and the main repo is updated to include the debs.

---

Originally posted by [arebgun](https://answers.ros.org/users/18/arebgun/) with karma: 2121 on 2012-05-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [John Hoare](https://answers.ros.org/users/159/john-hoare/) on 2012-05-14**:
Thanks, If I can get to it before you do I'll verify that it works. We are experiencing some other upgrade difficulties right now, so it may be a few days.

**Comment by [arebgun](https://answers.ros.org/users/18/arebgun/) on 2012-05-18**:
@John Hoare: dynamixel_motor stack should be Fuerte compatible now.